# Если встречается нечетный элемент, то перед ним и после него вставить новые элементы со значением 0

Tags: списки, c++

Изменил код! Теперь имеет такой вид:

```
void numb_1(TSNum *&Start){

TSNum *wp,*pp,*a,*b;
wp = Start;
pp = NULL;
if(Start == NULL){
    cout << "List is empty!\n";
    return;
}
while(wp != NULL){
    if(wp->numb %2 != 0){
        a = new TSNum;
        b = new TSNum;
        a->numb=0;
        b->numb=0;
        a->next = wp;
          a->prev = wp->prev;
          wp->prev = a;
          if (a->prev = wp->prev)
              a->prev->next = a;
           else
              Start = a;
          if (b->next = wp->next)
            b->next->prev = b;
          b->prev = wp;
          wp->next = b;
          wp = b;
        }
        wp = wp->next;
    }
}
```

Но работает только вставка после элемента, а перед элементом не вставляет 0

Comment: void numb_1(TSNum *&Start){
Что это за ад?

Comment: @Юра1996, а код структуры `TSNum`, функции `addToStart()` и `main()` написать забыли?

Comment: @avp, исправил!

Comment: А что такое `START_LIST` у Вас и как этот список (наверное указатель на TSNum) заполняется предлагаете догадываться?

--


Если `addToStart()` это функция, добавляющая новый элемент в голову списка, то она неправильная. Указатели `prev` не обновляются.

Comment: @Юра1996, если посмотреть внимательно, то Вы добавляя `b` после `wp` просто забыли установить `b->next`. Поэтому список и обрывается.

Мне кажется, что в основном цикле можно отказаться от `pp` (Вы ведь обеспечиваете, что первый элемент списка четный) и сразу править все указатели.

      ...
      a->next = wp;
      a->prev = wp->prev;
      wp->prev = a;
      a->prev->next = a;
      if (b->next = wp->next)
        b->next->prev = b;
      b->prev = wp;
      wp->next = b;
      wp = b; // маленькая оптимизация (b точно четный)
    }
    wp = wp->next;

Как-то в таком духе.

Comment: @avp, то есть так?

while(wp != NULL){
        if(wp->numb %2 != 0){
            a = new TSNum;
            b = new TSNum;
            a->numb = 0;
            b->numb = 0;
            a->next = wp;
            a->prev = wp->prev;
            wp->prev = a;
            a->prev->next = a;
            if (b->next = wp->next)
              b->next->prev = b;
            b->prev = wp;
            wp->next = b;
            wp = b; // маленькая оптимизация (b точно четный)
          }wp = wp->next;
        }

Comment: @avp, извините, не знаю как в комментариях форматировать

Comment: @Юра1996, для форматирования кода в комментарии надо начинать строки кода с 4-х пробелов и добавлять по пустой строке перед и после форматируемого фрагмента кода.

Ну, да, насколько вижу -- так. Я не проверял, но по идее должно работать (с учетом Вашей преамбулы) 

    if(Start->next == NULL || Start->numb%2 != 0){
     ...
      return;
    }

Иначе, при вставке перед `wp` надо вместо

       a->prev->next = a;

проверять

      if (a->prev = wp->prev)
         a->prev->next = a;
      else 
         Start = a; // новый первый в списке

Comment: @avp, я изменил код и поместил его в шапку темы! посмотрите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[[[@Юра1996](/users/17919/%D1%8E%D1%80%D0%B01996)](/users/17919/%D1%8E%D1%80%D0%B01996)](/users/17919/%D1%8E%D1%80%D0%B01996)](/users/17919/%D1%8E%D1%80%D0%B01996), комментарии кончились...

Вы убрали часть кода, которая гарантировала, что первый элемент списка четный и следовательно заголовок списка никогда не будет изменяться, поэтому вот  эти строчки

```
      a->next = wp;
      a->prev = wp->prev;
      wp->prev = a;
      if (a->prev = wp->prev)
          a->prev->next = a;
       else
          Start = a;
```

надо изменить.

Для общего случая код должен стать таким

```
while(wp != NULL) {
  if(wp->numb %2 != 0){
    // make zeros
    a = new TSNum;
    b = new TSNum;
    a->numb=0;
    b->numb=0;

    // add before
    a->next = wp;
    if (a->prev = wp->prev)
      a->prev->next = a;
    else
      Start = a;
    wp->prev = a;

    // add after
    if (b->next = wp->next)
      b->next->prev = b;
    b->prev = wp;
    wp->next = b;

    // b is even, so step forward
    wp = b;
  }
  wp = wp->next;
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

[[[[@Юра1996](/users/17919/%D1%8E%D1%80%D0%B01996)](/users/17919/%D1%8E%D1%80%D0%B01996)](/users/17919/%D1%8E%D1%80%D0%B01996)](/users/17919/%D1%8E%D1%80%D0%B01996), думаю Вы уже достаточно разобрались в такой реализации и Вам будет интересено взглянуть на более общий случай вставки в список и реализации Вашей конкретной задачи с его использованием.

Сделаем функцию, которая вставляет новый элемент в список *после* заданного или в начало списка, если вместо заданного элемента передаем NULL.

```
Tnum *
ins2list (Tnum **list, Tnum *after, Tnum *item)
{
  if (item->prev = after) {
    if (item->next = after->next)
      item->next->prev = item;
    after->next = item;
  } else {
    item->prev = 0;
    if (item->next = *list)
      item->next->prev = item;
    *list = item;
  }
  return item;
}
```

Я использую передачу указателя на указатель списка, а не ссылку, т.к. считаю использование ссылок в подобном контексте попросту вредным. Да, код получается может и чуть короче, но программисту, читающему вызывающую функцию абсолютно не понятно (без изучения вызываемой) может ли указатель быть изменен внутри вызова.

Тогда, остальной код может выглядеть так:

```
typedef struct numbs {
  int numb;
  struct numbs *next, *prev;
} Tnum;

static Tnum * randTnum (int vmax) {
  Tnum *x = new Tnum;
  x->numb = rand() % vmax;

  return x;
}

static void pri_list (Tnum *list) {
  for (;list; list = list->next)
    printf("%d [%p,%p]\n", list->numb, list->next, list->prev);
}

static void add_zodd (Tnum **plist) {
  for (Tnum *cur = *plist; cur; cur = cur->next)
    if (cur->numb & 1) {
      Tnum *z = new Tnum;
      z->numb = 0;
      ins2list(plist, cur->prev, z);
      z = new Tnum;
      z->numb = 0;
      cur = ins2list(plist, cur, z);
    }
}

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  int n = atoi(av[1] ? av[1] : "5");
  Tnum *list = 0, *last;

  // to begin of list (as stack push)
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    last = ins2list(&list, 0, randTnum(10));

  // 3 items to end of list
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
    last = ins2list(&list, last, randTnum(20));

  pri_list(list);
  puts("== add zeros around odd iems ==");
  add_zodd(&list);
  pri_list(list);
}
```

Обратите внимание, что функция `ins2list()` возвращает адрес вставляемого элемента. Часто это удобный прием при программировании списков.

Comment: @Юра1996, обновил ответ. Может будет интересно.